# Silverlight: Scroll issue with RichTextBox Selection property

Tags: silverlight, scroll, richtextbox, selection

I have a Grid in silverlight having a lot of different controls.
In the last row of Grid, I have a RichTextBox.

To write something in RichTextBox, first we have to scroll down to that because controls are too much.

Each time we open that Grid, all the controls are initiated with some initial data.
Now there is a problem with this line

`this.rtb.Selection.Text = "Initial Text";`

What this line do is, it set text into RichTextBox control and also set focus on it, as a result my scroll bar move to the bottom, which is very annoying.

I want this text assigned to it but scroller should stay at top.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// create a paragraph
Paragraph prgParagraph = new Paragraph();

// create some text, and add it to the paragraph
Run rnMyText = new Run();
rnMyText.Text = "This is some example text with a ";

prgParagraph.Inlines.Add(rnMyText);

// add the paragraph to the RTB
rbtMyRichTextBox.Blocks.Add(prgParagraph);
```